# Is it possible to connect the if-code to the else-code in the flow diagram (Java)?

Tags: java, if-statement

I've been working on this problem for 3 hours and I'm stuck

I have two conditions and I don't necessarily want to split them up using an `if-else` statement, what I mean by that is given this flow diagram:

[image]

I would need the `if code` to only be executed if its conditions are `true` and then to pass through the `else code`, so essentially the outgoing arrow of the `if code` would end on top of the `else code`, I know this is not the best in java as my textbook warns against it

[image]

maybe I can illustrate my problem with some code

```
        int digit = -1;
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter your choise (1-6): ");     
            if (in.hasNextInt()) 
            {
                digit = in.nextInt();
            }
            else 
            {
                in.next();
                System.out.println(" ");
                System.out.println("This is a wrong input. Please try again!");
            }
        }while (digit > 6 || digit < 1);
// the program is asking the user to read off of a menu with number 1-6 
// representing different menu items, this ensures that the user inputs 
// is an integer 1-6 and asks again if not an integer 1-6       

        
        String digitName;
        switch (digit)
        {
            case 1: digitName = "Hamburger"; break;
            case 2: digitName = "Pizza"; break;
            case 3: digitName = "Noodle"; break;
            case 4: digitName = "Salad"; break;
            case 5: digitName = "Sandwhich"; break;
            case 6: digitName = "Finish the order!"; break;
            default: digitName = ""; break;
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Your choice is: " + digitName + ".");
// the switch statement allows the right menu item to be printed in the above print statements
        
        if (digit == 6) 
        {
            System.out.println("No need to pay for the delivery fee.");
            System.out.println("The total price is $0.0.");
            System.out.println("Thank you for using Online Order Program!");
// if digit == 6 then then user would like to exit
        }
        else 
        {
// given the choice of the user from the menu, other than exiting, the program
// asks the user if they would like meat with their order and this ensures/only 
// accepts an input from the user "yes" or "no", if not then prompts the user 
// again until "yes" or "no" not lower or upper case sensitive  
            System.out.print("Would you like to have some meat on your " + digitName + "? (Enter yes or no, don't worry about capitals) "); 
            String likeSomeMeatNul = in.next();
            String likeSomeMeat = likeSomeMeatNul.toLowerCase();
                        
            if (!likeSomeMeat.equals("yes") && !likeSomeMeat.equals("no")) 
            {
            
                do 
                {
                    System.out.println("\nThis is a wrong input. Please try again!");
                    System.out.print("Would you like to have some meat on your " + digitName + "? (Enter yes or no, don't worry about capitals) ");
                    String someMeat = in.next();
                    likeSomeMeat = someMeat.toLowerCase();
            
                }while (!likeSomeMeat.equals("yes") && !likeSomeMeat.equals("no"));
            }
        
// if the user would like meat with their order then the program needs to know 
// which kind, in this case "beef" or "pork" and the program only accepts inputs
// "beef" and "pork" not lower or upper case sensitive      
            if (likeSomeMeat.equals("yes")) 
            {
                System.out.print("Beef or Pork? (Enter Beef or Pork, don't worry about capitals) ");    
                String beefOrPorkNul = in.next();
                String beefOrPork = beefOrPorkNul.toLowerCase();
            
                if (!beefOrPork.equals("beef") && !beefOrPork.equals("pork")) 
                {
                    do 
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nThis is a wrong input. Please try again!");
                        System.out.print("Beef or Pork? (Enter Beef or Pork, don't worry about capitals) ");
                        String enterBeefOrPork = in.next();
                        beefOrPork = enterBeefOrPork.toLowerCase();
            
                    }while (!beefOrPork.equals("pork") && !beefOrPork.equals("beef"));
        }

// but if the user does not want any meat with their order
// say they ordered #3 Noodles, they just want noodles without meat
// I need to prompt the user if still like to order more food
// it works if the user wants their order with meat, and the program
// terminates if the user inputs "no" for "Would you like to have some meat?"       
        
        System.out.print("Would you like to have more food? (Enter yes or no, don't worry about capitals) ");
        String moreFoodNul = in.next();
        String moreFood = moreFoodNul.toLowerCase();
        
        if (!moreFood.equals("yes") && !moreFood.equals("no")) 
        {
            do 
            {
                System.out.println("\nThis is a wrong input. Please try again!");
                System.out.print("Would you like to have more food? (Enter yes or no, don't worry about capitals) ");
                String enter_more_food = in.next();
                moreFood = enter_more_food.toLowerCase();
            
            }while (!moreFood.equals("yes") && !moreFood.equals("no"));
        }
//only accepts "yes" or "no" not case sensitive
```

I thought it would check to see if the condition inside the `if (like_some_meat.equals("yes"))` is true or false, if true then execute and move on to the next line, if false move on to the next line, but this clearly isn't the case... it's looking for what happens if it's false and since I didn't put anything, the program terminates. I goes through if `like_some_meat.equals("yes")` is true however.

How do I get something to execute only if the condition is true and keep moving forward if false? If possible. I'm not sure my code is salvageable if I would have to split it into two separate branches.

Comment: It's still not quite clear, but more understandable as you edit; thank you. What do you mean about your textbook warns you against it?

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what you mean by moving forward, from the code snippet you shared I can't figure out where the if block `likeSomeMeat.equals("yes)"` ends.

Comment: Your diagrams have nothing to do with your code.

Comment: @Neil the second diagram is from my textbook

Comment: @rakesh I edited my code and added some comments, let me know if it's better

Comment: The edited indentation is *much* more understandable. The second diagram helps; that is, this is non-sense in Java; `if-else` blocks nestle, but there is no way to form a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) in general.

Comment: You are over-thinking it. `if (condition) { do-if-code }; do-else-code;`

Comment: @Bohemian I think I got my code to work now  Eclipse IDE is lagging at the moment, but I think I got what I wanted, as Stephen C mentioned it mostly had to do with the `}` at the end of else, thanks for looking at my post! I can always post the full code if you like...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so I will translate your flowchart into Java so that it is easier to write :-)

```
if (condition) {
   // if code
} else {
   // else code
}
```

If you change the arrow in your flowchart to that the "if code" feeds directly into the "else code" box, that is equivalent to this Java code:

```
if (condition) {
   // if code
}
// else code
```

In short, the "else code" is no longer conditional.

Now for your "textbook" example.  There are basically two ways to write that in Java:

```
if (insideUS) {
    if (continentalUS) {
        shippingCost = 5;
    } else {
        shippingCost = 10;
    }
} else {
    shippingCost = 10;
}
```

or

```
if (insideUS && continentalUS) {
        shippingCost = 5;
} else {
    shippingCost = 10;
}
```

The construct that your textbook warns you about is *not expressible* in Java.  It is not possible to "jump" into a block like that.  Java doesn't allow it.  (Some old languages do allow that kind of thing.  But it is a bad idea to do it.)

But note that what the textbook is saying is different to what your original flowchart is saying.

---

If you look carefully at your (re-styled) code, you should be able to see the problem.  The `else` block does not end at

```
String likeSomeMeat = likeSomeMeatNul.toLowerCase();
```

as your manual indentation implies that it should.  In fact the `}` that matches the `else {` is **on the last line**, so the `else` part extends right to the end.  That would explain why nothing happens when the condition is `true`.

(In the code where you test `likeSomeMeat` etcetera, there is no `else` part, so I'm not sure what you were asking about there.  But I think that the real answer is to read your code carefully and think about it.  There is nothing really difficult or magical about if / else logic.)

---

Hint: if you are using an IDE, it will have an automatic code re-indenter ... and probably a simple way to see what `}` matches a given `{`.

Comment: everything inside the `if` brackets{} is executed if the condition is true, if not, move on to the else code? My program only moves on to the else code if the condition for `if` is satisfied, if not it just stops :(

Comment: Fix the indentation, etcetera, and I will try to understand what you are saying.

Comment: Seems like what you asked? If `condition` is true, `if`, `else`. If `condition` is false, `else`.

Comment: Ok I'm on it, by standard Java identifier conventions do you mean camel notation? :)

Comment: Yes.  That's what I mean.  The point of style rules are to make it easier for *other people* to read your code.  So you should make sure that your code follows the rules **before** you ask other people to read it.

Comment: Working on it !

Comment: I don't think camel case is necessarily as important as having consistent tabs.

Comment: (I agree.  In this case.)

Comment: I find that `if-else` blocks are much more readable then those diagrams.

Comment: @StephenC thanks for the help! I managed to get my code to work